# Python PyGame making a Snake Game

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently making a snake game but I have come across something I do not understand.

```
def moveHead():
    global snakeList
    lenlist = list(range(1,len(snakeList)))
    lenlist.reverse()
    for i in lenlist:
        snakeList[i] = snakeList[i-1]
    snakeList[0][1] += 30
    print("AF")
    print(snakeList)
```

Basically, `snakeList` is a list of coordinates. For example `[[25,25],[0,0]]`

What's supposed to happen is that is that the item shifted to the right except of the element in index 0. In the example mentioned, `[0,0]` would turn into `[25,25]`, and the line below the for loop would change the whole thing to `[[25,55],[25,25]]`.

For some reason the second item would also copy the changed item in the front, turning `snakeList` into `[[25,55],[25,55]]`.

Answer (score 0):

With `snakeList[i] = snakeList[i-1]`, you don't actually have two sub-lists. The assignment just copies the reference to the sub-list, not the actual sub-list, so both `snakeList[i]` and `snakeList[i-1]` refer to the same sub-list after the assignment, thus when changing one element the other changes respectively.

In order to get the desired result you should use the builtin `list.copy()` method:

```
snakeList[i] = snakeList[i-1].copy()
```

Which after running your code with the above correction the result is:

```
AF
[[25, 55], [25, 25]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey it seems you're taking a very long way of doing something that python has built-in functionality for

So it seems you'd like every item in the list except the first item?

You can achieve this by some manipulation with the ':' in the array

```
# first we can get the last index of the array, e.g. snakeList
last_i = len(snakeList)
# then we can use the part of the array we'd like, in this case everything else except the first
snake_list_copy = snakeList[1:last_i]
# you can then make use of python's simple array manipulation to add any new items to the array
snakeList = snake_list_copy + [ new_items ] # this will create a new array with new items at the end
```

As a quick example, consider the following

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
last_i = len(a)
b = a[1:last_i] # b is now [4, 6, 8]
b = [0,2] + b + [10,12] # b is now [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve your issue:

```py
def moveHead():
    global snakeList
    snakeList.insert(0, snakeList[0].copy())
    del snakeList[-1]
    snakeList[0][1] += 30
```

---

> What's supposed to happen is that is that the item shifted to the right except of the element in index 0. In the example mentioned, `[0,0]` would turn into `[25,25]`, and the line below the for loop would change the whole thing to `[[25,55],[25,25]]`.

No. Note the indices are reversed by:

> ```py
> lenlist = list(range(1,len(snakeList)))
> lenlist.reverse()
> ```

If `len(snakeList)` is 4, then after this 2 lines the content of `lenlist` is `[3, 2, 1]`.

So the for loop operates in reverse order. If the content of `snakeList` is `[[0,0],[25,0],[50,0],[75,0]]`, then after processing the loop

> ```py
> for i in lenlist:
>    snakeList[i] = snakeList[i-1]
> ```

the content of the list is `[[0, 0], [25, 0], [50, 0], [75, 0]]`

What now happens is, that the 1st and 2nd element of the list refer to the same object.

So after the line

> ```py
> snakeList[0][1] += 30
> ```

The content of the list is `[[0, 30], [0, 30], [25, 0], [50, 0]]`.

If you repeat the process, then the content of the list will change to `[[0, 60], [0, 60], [0, 60], [25, 0]]` and further `[[0, 90], [0, 90], [0, 90], [0, 90]]`. Now all the elements of the list refer to the same list object.

You can get rid of that, by doing a shallow copy ([`list.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)) of the list element (each element of the list is a list, too):

```py
snakeList[i] = snakeList[i-1].copy()
```

---

If you want to move the elements of the list to the right, then appending a new element at the head of the list and deleting the tail element of the list will do the job, too:

```py
snakeList.insert(0, snakeList[0].copy())
del snakeList[-1]
```